# Webscraping a dynamic page with filtered table

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

I am trying to parse the page https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/knhy11, where I need the info from a Dividends history table, which is dynamically filtered by pages.

So, by doing

```
url = 'https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/knhy11'
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
text = webpage.decode('utf-8')

spt = text.split('\n')

file1 = open("myfile.txt","w")
for line in spt:
    file1.write(line)
file1.close()
```

I am able to get the first (default) page, but the info from the other pages doesn't come.
How could I fix that?

Tkx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full data is located in an `input` tag with id `results` in the `value` attribute. The result is in JSON.

You can use beautifulsoup to parse html like in the following script :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json

r = requests.get("https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/knhy11")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

data = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "TIPO": t["et"], 
        "DATA COM": t["ed"], 
        "PAGAMENTO": t["pd"], 
        "VALOR": t["v"]
    }
    for t in json.loads(soup.find("input",{"id":"results"})["value"])
])

print(data)
```

Output:

```
          TIPO    DATA COM   PAGAMENTO  VALOR
0   Rendimento  30/09/2020  14/10/2020   0.64
1   Rendimento  31/08/2020  14/09/2020   0.65
2   Rendimento  31/07/2020  13/08/2020   0.45
3   Rendimento  30/06/2020  13/07/2020   0.32
4   Rendimento  29/05/2020  12/06/2020   0.30
5   Rendimento  30/04/2020  14/05/2020   0.50
6   Rendimento  31/03/2020  14/04/2020   0.70
.............................................
.............................................
18  Rendimento  29/03/2019  11/04/2019   0.73
19  Rendimento  28/02/2019  15/03/2019   0.64
20  Rendimento  31/01/2019  13/02/2019   0.49
21  Rendimento  28/12/2018  14/01/2019   0.36
22  Rendimento  30/11/2018  13/12/2018   0.56
23  Rendimento  31/10/2018  14/11/2018   0.57
24  Rendimento  28/09/2018  11/10/2018   0.32
25  Rendimento  31/08/2018  14/09/2018   0.42
26  Rendimento  31/07/2018  13/08/2018   0.11
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/Scraping64488464)

Comment: Life saviour, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.